# PyTorch custom DataLoader working with multiple CSVs

Tags: pytorch, iterator, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to define a customized PyTorch DataLoader able to efficiently read from different **huge** CSVs without load them into memory. The problem is defined as follows. For simplicity, let's suppose I have two CSVs

```
1.csv:

1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

```
2.csv:

10,11,12
13,14,15
16,17,18
```

For simplicity, let's also assume a batch size of 1. The generator should produce two tensors:

```
Tensor_1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Tensor_2: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

This is because for each valid index I am applying an history window equals to 2 and I am then flattening the sample.

Following the answer at [What is the fastest way to load data from multiple csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941749/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-load-data-from-multiple-csv-files) I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
from functools import lru_cache
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch

@lru_cache()
def get_sample_count_by_file(path: Path) -> int:
    c = 0
    with path.open() as f:
        for line in f:
            c += 1
    return c

class CSVDataset:
    def __init__(self, csv_directory: str, extension: str = ".csv"):
        self.directory = Path(csv_directory)
        self.files = sorted((f, get_sample_count_by_file(f)) for f in self.directory.iterdir() if f.suffix == extension)
        self._sample_count = sum(f[-1] for f in self.files)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._sample_count

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        current_count = 0

        history_window = 2
        my_idx=idx+2

        for file_, sample_count in self.files:
            if current_count <= my_idx < current_count + sample_count:
                break  
            current_count += sample_count

        file_idx = my_idx - current_count # the index we want to access in file_
        if file_idx < 2:
            file_idx += 2

        with file_.open() as f:
            data = []
            for i, line in enumerate(f):
                if i >= file_idx-history_window and i <= file_idx:
                    for v in line.split(","):
                        data.append(float(v))

            data = np.array(data)
            return torch.from_numpy(data)


dataset = CSVDataset("<PATH CONTAINING CSVs>")
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1)

pprint(list(enumerate(loader)))
```

It perfectly works for the first file but there are troubles when it switches to the second CSV (there are some duplicates because of the wrong management of indices). How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about using your `CSVDataset` for one csv only, and then use [`torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset) to concat all individual csv datasets into a single one. Pytorch will take care of the indexing for you, as long as the indexing within each `CSVDataset` are coherent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shai! Can you provide a code sample to better explain your idea please?

Comment: Edit: It seems that [torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset) concatenates files keeping all of them in memory. My files are huge CSVs so this would not be a solution.